# Law of Maximum for Brownian motion before hitting 0

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion started at $a>0$ and let $T_{0}$ be the first time $W$ hits $0$ . The goal is to find the law of $\sup _{t \leq T_{0}} W_{t}$.

My initial attempt is as follows: Reflection principle helps establish the law of $\sup_{s\leq t} W_s$ for fixed $t$. Then we can condition on the $T_0$ and use law of total probability. Is it a valid argument?

I appreciate either hints or solution to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Introduce for each $b>a$ the first hitting time $T_b$ of $b$. Then $$\sup_{t \le T_0} W_t \ge b \iff T_b < T_0.$$ The gambler's ruin theorem (or Doob martingale stopping theorem applied to $T_0 \wedge T_b$) shows that this occurs with probability $a/b$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the connection to martingale properties here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y>a$,
$$
\mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_{0\le s\le T_0}W_s<y\right)=\mathsf{P}(T_0<T_y)=1-\frac{a}{y}.
$$
This probability can be deduced from the fact that
$$
a=\mathsf{E}B_{T_0\wedge T_y}=y\mathsf{P}(T_0\ge T_y).
$$